# Change Main in WPF project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, model-view-controller, program-entry-point

Always annoyed me how C# wants to do the startup for you. So now I am trying to make my own main method. It's not working:

I have provided this main method:

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public static void Main()
{
    Model model= new Model();
    Controller controller = new Controller(model);
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow(controller, model);
}
```

This method is run, but I cant see anything visual.
I think I miss something from the following normal main code:

```
Application.App app = new Application.App();
app.InitializeComponent();
app.Run();
```

I have tried overriding OnStartUp witht the same code, but that throws an exception.
If you have other solutions I am willing to hear. I just can't see why my MainWindow has to be created first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right: you need to instantiate an Application and call Run on it.  (You'd do this in Main.)  To make it show your window when it runs, there are three options:

- Use the Run(Window) overload, e.g. `MainWindow w = ...; new MyApp().Run(w);`
- Set the StartupUri e.g. `myApp.StartupUri = new Uri(...); myApp.Run();`
- Do the Show in the Startup event or OnStartup override e.g. `myApp.Startup += (...) => new MainWindow().Show();`

Examples of manual startup code are shown in MSDN under the [Application.Run()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597010.aspx) and [Application.Run(Window)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597011.aspx) entries - these should get you started!  The Run() overload also discusses *why* Application.Run is needed and what it does e.g. starting the dispatcher loop.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed to know :)

Answer (score 0):

> Always annoyed me how C# wants to do the startup for you. So now I am trying to make my own main method. It's not working:

C# doesn't do the startup for you.  It inserts code that does it for you.  You could always change the code and so whatever you wanted.  First thing I would do if I were you - Right click the project file and select Properties.  Under Application (the top tab) - see Startup Object.

You can select the form

Also - You're missing a line if you want the window to appear:

```
window.Show();
```

Comment: window.Show will, I believe, cause the window to appear, and then immediately disappear as the process exits (because Show doesn't wait for the window to close).

Comment: then use window.ShowDialog();