# Application.Startup event limitations (bug?)

Tags: c#, wpf, window

It says, I can use [`Startup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx) event for many things, like initialization, creating multiple forms, blablabla.

However, try to create a new WPF application and add this event handler:

```
    private void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = new Window();
    }
```

And after closing main window your application will hang up in the memory. Pausing executing in VS at that moment will drop ugly <strike>crash</strike> call stack window with a lot of calls somewhere far away from my source code.

Any thoughts?

P.S.: I need to instantiate all of my windows for self-learning configuration purpose once. Should I use some other place?

[image: Call stack]

---

Let me give a better example (example above is good to reproduce the problem, seems it's hard to understand what I am actually doing). I remove `StartupUri` and then:

```
    private void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // un-comment this line to reproduce the problem:
        // Window window = new Window();

        // actual implementation will be
        // Window1 window1 = new Window1();
        // Window2 window2 = new Window2();
        // Window3 window3 = new Window3();
        // Window4 window4 = new Window4();
        // ...

        // start main window as usually
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
```

And why do I need instances of windows (window1, ..2, ..3, ...)? Because their content will be inspected to create a list of controls for which I want to save configuration. Some of these windows will **never** be shown to the user (to example, if he is not admin), some of them are popups, some are editors, etc. So I do not want to display them. But at any application startup the configuration has to be created and saved. And I am looking now for the place to do so.

Surprisingly, using dedicated event `Startup` seems have some *problems* with creating multiple windows but *not displaying* them. Question is why and how to solve it.

---

Testing a bit more. Try this code and explain me, why application is closed without showing **any** window?

```
    private void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = new Window();
        window.Close(); // closing without opening window

        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show();
        //mainWindow = new MainWindow(); // can be un-commented, for absolutely no effect
        mainWindow.Show();
        mainWindow.Show();
        mainWindow.Show();
        mainWindow.Show(); // you will not see mainWindow at all, all Show doing nothing
    }
```

More questions. What do I do?

---

Something what works, but smells:

```
    private void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = new Window();

        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.ShowDialog();
        Shutdown();
    }
```

Notice, calling `ShowDialog` (which will make event handler waiting for that window closing) and calling `Shutdown` right after.

It is still not clear what is the problem in the `Startup` event handler to create instances of some windows. Any ideas?

Comment: What crash are you getting?

Comment: @RohitVats, screenshot added. Can you try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: It is not a crash window, just the stack trace.  Call Show() on the window so the user can close it and get the app to exit.

Comment: @HansPassant, and how to fix it without showing window?

Comment: I have no idea why you are doing this.  Just call Close() again, I guess.

Comment: @HansPassant, I do it to have instance. Calling `window.Close()` will make `mainWindow` not even displayed. See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solution, which seems pretty good to me. Idea is similar to `winforms` - do everything in the `Main`.

This, however, is a bit *tricky* in wpf (I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1948170/1997232) question as a guide):

- Remove `StartupUri` from `App.xaml`;
- Set `App.xaml` property `Build Action` to `Page` (this sounds strange, but it works for desktop application). This will remove `Main` method from auto-generated classes (*App.g.cs* and *App.g.i.cs*).
- Add `Main` method manually into `Application`:

.

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Window window1 = new Window();
        Window window2 = new Window();
        Window window3 = new Window();
        // ...

        MainWindow start = new MainWindow();
        start.ShowDialog();

        SomeOtherWindow next = new MainWindow();
        next.ShowDialog();

    }
}
```

Now I can directly control which window to show and when (program flow control), as well as there is no more **bug** with not-closing application when creating instances of windows without displaying them.

The suspicious things are this `Page` setting and that fact, what I do not instantiate `Application`, nor I call `Run()`. I do not know yet, if it will be a problem in the future. Would be nice to know it for sure.

---

It might be necessary to init application still (to load resources?), then

```
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.InitializeComponents();

        // ... the rest
        // possibly app.MainWindow = start; or app.MainWindow = next;
        // if only 1 window, then app.Run(new MainWindow());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

By doing this, the window you just created has become the main window: the one specified in `StartupUri` will only be created right after the start up event. By default, the main window must be closed for the application to shutdown. Since it's never shown, the user has no opportunity to do this and the application seems to hang forever. What you're seeing when the execution is paused is a normal message loop, there is no crash here. Add `window.Show()` to see your real 'main' window.

Remove the `StartupUri` attribute from your `App.xaml` if you decide to instantiate the main window manually. Alternatively, keep the attribute and instantiate the additional windows after the `Loaded` event from the main window has been fired.

Comment: Ok, I removed `StartupUri` and starting main window in `Startup` event **after** that row (which creates `Window` instance). Still application halts when closing **main** window.

Comment: Regarding `Loaded` event, do you know where can I see the order of events? Because if I read it right, [`Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) is when element is rendered, which for me sounds like `shown first timer` event. But, as I said, I am not willing to display that form at all.  It is interesting, does any of upvoters bother to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "after" that row. You should remove the StartupUri in the .xaml file. Add Show() calls for testing purposes to see the created windows. You'll notice one is still opened. Yes, Loaded is when the element is rendered, use the first solution instead (startup event without StartupUri in the App.xaml file).

Comment: See question edit. Yes, I removed `StartupUri` in .xaml file. And yes, it will **work** if I add `Show` for each instantiated window. Now, how to make application working **without showing windows** (I mentioned this many time)? Regarding `Loaded`, when exactly does it triggers? Will it trigger when I instantiate or just before displaying? But displaying means *show window* and if you read me accurately, this is **not what I want**. Question is still opened: why instantiating window (without showing it) in `Startup` event **is a problem** and what to do to fix it?

Comment: It's not a problem, it's the default behavior! If you don't want to wait for the main window to be closed for the application to shutdown (because you *chose* to hide the said window), please call `Application.Shutdown` manually when you feel it's the right time. For example, when a specific window has been closed. Indeed, `Loaded` triggers just before displaying so that won't work for your case.

Comment: I don't understand that *default behavior*. I create instance of some class in event handler. **What is the problem** with that? Idea with `Application.Shutdown` is not bad, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but since I got there somehow, here is a way to close the application when the main window is closed:

```
ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
```

You can set it in `OnStartup` method of `App.xaml.cs`
This way, even if you had some other windows opened, the whole app will shut down.