# Where to do something before anything?

Tags: c#, wpf, program-entry-point

Sorry for confusing title =D

In `WindowsForms` I have `Main` method, which I can use to do *something* before creating or displaying main form. For example, processing command line parameters, showing splash window and preloading configuration, having several windows shown one after each other, *main loop* (when there is a repeatable working sequence, then `Main` is pretty good place to put there `do{}while`), etc.

Which is the best analog for such `Main` method in `WPF`?

I tried to use [`Application.Startup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx) event, but it has some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22460116/1997232).

I could think of creating wpf application programmatically somehow (then I should be unbound from xaml autogenerated `Main` and can have my own). But this all sounds too complicated. I probably missing something very simple.

Comment: Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955663/how-to-build-splash-screen-in-windows-forms-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455703/splash-screen-example

Comment: I know it's off-topic, but I just like the existential question title!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is ... do everything in the `Main`.

For this I have to disable auto-generating `Main` (by setting `App.xaml` property `BuildAction` to `Page`, instead of default `ApplicationDefinition`) and then I can create own `Main` inside `Application` class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

There I have full control over when and how to display windows, do initialization, deinit and such.

Answer (score 4):

Moving from WinForms development to WPF development can involve a little bit of a change of mindset. I would look into [WPF and MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), there are plenty of resources on the web.

After that, you should start looking at the various frameworks which build on this, such as [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx), [Caliburn.Micro](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), [MVVMLight](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) etc, which all have various tutorials and documentation around building WPF applications with splash screens and composite windows.

For what it's worth, `protected override void OnStartup` in `App.xaml.cs` is where you'd want to "do something, before anything", like, show a splash screen before loading your main screen.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but override `OnStartup` doesn't works (same as subscribing to `Startup` event), see my issue in question if you want. I am just started with studying WPF and MVVM, probably I am making some mistakes (not planning to use any side frameworks yet, until I really find good reasoning for a beginner to go straight into, to example, Prism). My question is not how to make splash window, but how to organize it. `Main` is generated, event/override is not working good, so where to put my code before anything, which will not cause problems to the application itself?